# PHP, Что за конструкция "$a=(array) $b" обозначает

Tags: php

недано начал изучать Php, в скрипте встретил такую конструкцию

```
$a=(array) $b
```

не могу понять что она делает, объясните пожалуйста на пальцах.

Comment: Из мануала:
Допускаются следующие приведения типов:

(int), (integer) - приведение к integer;
(bool), (boolean) - приведение к boolean;
(float), (double), (real) - приведение к float;
(string) - приведение к string;
(array) - приведение к array;
(object) - приведение к object;
(unset) - приведение к NULL (PHP 5);
Приведение типа (binary) и поддержка префикса b были добавлены в PHP 5.2.1
Ваш пример:
$a=(array) $b;   // $a - это будет тип array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это приведение к типу, а именно приведение к типу `array` переменной `$b`. Такое может использоваться например в том случае, когда переменная `$b` содержит данные типа `stdClass`.

Answer (score 1):

[Это приведение типов.](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.type-juggling.php) Обычно используется когда вам нужно получить массив, а на вход вам дают бог знает что.

```
function test($b) {
    $a = (array) $b;
    foreach ($a as $c) {
        echo "c=$c\n";
    }
}
```

С этим приведением типа функцию можно вызывать с одним аргументом так:

```
test(123);
```

И так:

```
test(array(123, 456));
```

Если же приведение типов не делать, то функция не сработает с ошибкой:

```
PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Comment: Спасибо всем, разобрался

Answer (score 1):

по поводу скалярных типов данных, если вы сделаете что-то вроде

```
$a = 777; // или $a = 'qwerty'; или $a = true;
$array = (array)$a;
var_dump($array);
```

то вам вернется массив, который содержит в качестве первого элемента вашу исходную переменную

```
array(1) {
[0]=>
bool(true) // или int(777) или string(qwerty)
}
```